# Object suddenly missing from HttpServletRequest

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, weblogic, java-ee-5

I print a list directly in the servlet using the print writer and the list prints.

When I try to put in the jsp however the list doesn't print whether I use JSTL or scriptlets.

I tried to test in JSTL and scriptlet if the object is null and turns out that it is!

Why does this happen and how can I fix this?

Servlet code that works

```
for (Artist artist:artists){
    resp.getWriter().println(artist.getName());
}
```

Servlet code that puts object in the request

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
    throws IOException {        

    ApplicationContext ctx = 
        new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("com/helloworld/beans/helloworld-context.xml");

    ArtistDao artistDao = (ArtistDao) ctx.getBean("artistDao");
    List<Artist> artists = null;
    try {
        artists = artistDao.getAll();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    req.setAttribute("artists", artists);

    try {
        req.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(req, resp);
    } catch (ServletException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

scriptlet code that suddenly finds the object null

```
<% 

    List<Artist> artists = (List<Artist>) request.getAttribute("artists");

    if (artists == null) {
        out.println("artists null");
    }
    else {
        for (Artist artist: artists){
            out.println(artist.getName());
        }
    }
%>
```

Even the jstl code seems to agree

```
<c:if test="${artists eq null}">
    Artists are null
</c:if>

<c:forEach var="artist" items="${artists}">
${artist.name}
</c:forEach>
```

For my app I am using weblogic, spring 2.5.6 and ibatis.

Comment: Do you have the chance to try on a different app server? I don't see any problems with the code - setAttribute/requestDispatch is a common pattern.

Comment: I am required to use weblogic here at work but I'll try testing in tomcat. Like you, I have been thinking it's a problem with the app server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just discovered inadvertently while trying to fix my directory structure in WebContent/

My previous directory structure was 
WEB-CONTENT/
    - META-INF/ 
    - WEB-INF/
    index.jsp

Then I tried to create a folder jsp in WEB-CONTENT and placed index.jsp there. It works!

My current directory structure now is 
WEB-CONTENT/
    - META-INF/ 
    - WEB-INF/
    ***- jsp/***
        ***-index.jsp***

I don't know why it works but it did.

Anyone here with any idea why?

Comment: Hi, you should probably add this to your original question, rather than answering your own question.

Comment: Or maybe I should post a new question =))

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the app server is resetting your request object. You can work around this by creating a new request object, that wraps your original request, and pass that to the reqest dispatcher.

e.g.
    MyHttpRequest myRequest = new MyHttpRequest(req);
    myRequest.setAttribute(...);
    req.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(myRequest, resp);

And the MyHttpReqest code:

```
   class MyHttpRequest extends HttpServletRequestWrapper
   {
      Map attributes = new HashMap();
      MyHttpRequest(HttpRequest original) {
         super(original);
      }
      @Override
      public void setAttribute(Object key, Object value) {
          attributes.put(key, value);
      }

      public Object getAttribute(Object key) {
          Object value = attributes.get(key);
          if (value==null)
              value = super.getAttribute(key);
          return value;
      }

      // similar for removeAttribute 
   }
```

Comment: How do not make the app server reset my request object?

Comment: I don't know. It's not meant to, and I'm only guessing that this is the problem - I don't have access to a weblogic instance to test. Can you try the code I posted? You can then debug and check that you are getting the same MyHttpRequest instance in your JSP.

Comment: Can you confirm that you're adding the attributes on MyHttpRequest and not the usaual HttpServletRequest instance? The original code is a little misleading, so I've updated it.

Comment: will do but I'll have to get back to you tomorrow. Not in the office now. :) thanks for the help!

Comment: I believe if servlet request class is not working then wrapper also behaves like the same. Surprising behaviour of the server which I never come across.

Comment: @RaviG - The wrapper doesn't necessarily have to behave the same since we are explicitly adding the attribute to our wrapper - the attributes are stored separately from the request attributes provided by the app server.

Comment: @mdma I tried your solution. Unfortunately it still doesn't work. However when I placed my index.jsp inside another folder in WEB-CONTENT/ it does (see my answer for more info) but then I won't need it anymore since the common pattern also works as well.

Comment: Great that you found a solution. This here was just a shot in the dark.

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends on the web server. But without changing your previous directory structure,

try putting the list in session like this

```
req.getSession(false).setAttribute("artists", artists);
```

and in your jsp,

write

```
List<Artist> artists = (List<Artist>) request.getSession(false).getAttribute("artists");
```

I think my approach will work for all web servers.

Comment: I tried this also but it didn't work too with the first directory structure above. It was really frustrating! Now that you've mentioned the session,  I haven't tried if the session works with the second directory structure above. 

What does the problem have to do with directory structure you masy ask? Believe me I don't see the correlation either but it works. @-)